# Const member function when operation has clear side effects

Tags: c++

Imagine I have a class "Window" with a member function "show" which causes the underlying window to become visible on the screen.

Because I'm calling an underlying windows API to achieve this I'm not in any way altering the state of my "Window" object and yet clearly there is a large, obvious change in state of my window caused by calling this ( a window appearing on the screen and being able to be interacted with by users)

So I should declare my function as -

```
void Window::show() const;
```

because as far as the Window object is concerned this function doesn't change any state and therefore can be called on "const Window" objects. But somehow that doesn't seem right as calling that function clearly in some sense changes the state of the object.

Comment: Agreed. Even if it can technically be done it would be hard to argue it doesn't violate the notion of 'constness' to do so.

Comment: Thinking about this, it would be valuable to be able to have functions take "const Window&" paramaters knowing that those functions could only look at the window, not change it at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you’re probably grappling with is that C++ has no notion of purity, that is, whether or not a function has side-effects. `const` member functions only make the promise that the state of the *object itself* will not be modified.

However, some objects logically consist of more state than what the instance actually contains. This comes up very often when an object’s role is to interact with state managed by another library—especially a GUI library.

Therefore, while `show()` can *incidentally* be marked `const`, it logically should *not* be. If it were truly `const`, then you would expect a function such as `is_visible()` to return the same value both before and after the call to `show()`, and clearly that is not the case.

In other words, `const` functions are those that change nothing about the object *that you can observe through its public interface*. That’s the reasoning behind, for example, marking some member functions `const` but using a `mutable` member to do internal bookkeeping.

Comment: A lot depends on what you understand the abstraction of `Window` to be.  I think you can argue the question both ways.  Similarly, you can argue against any `const`, on any function; a function like `is_visible()`, if it resolves to a request to the window manager, may change state without you calling any member function.

Comment: @JamesKanze: There’s still a difference between functions that retrieve a value that’s subject to change (`get_x()`) and those that actually subject a value to change (`show()`). In a game, for example, you want `get_x()` to return the `x` component of an object *at the current moment*. The changes in `x` over time come from elsewhere, and you are merely observing them.

Comment: @JonPurdy I agree (more or less); logically, one might say that the changes are coming from elsewhere, so the function should be `volatile`.  But there are good reasons not to do this.  On the whole, I suspect that it's one of the arguments against using `const` at all on objects which are accessed from more or less everywhere.  (I'm not saying that I agree with this.  Just that it's an argument which could be presented, and should probably be considered.)

Answer (score 7):

This is the classical logical const vs. bitwise const question.  It was
debated hotly back when I was learning C++ (early 1990's), but since
then, I think there is a consensus in favor of logical const: if the
logical state of an object changes, then the function should not be
`const` (even if the compiler would allow `const`), and if the logical
state doesn't change, then the function should be `const` (even if you 
need `mutable` or to cast away const to do; e.g. a cached result of a
computation).

In the specific case of `Window::show`, it's hard to say.  Is the fact
that the window is being displayed part of its "logical state" or not.

Answer (score 4):

It may not change any state of any variable physically held within the Window object, but it does change the state of the thing the Window represents, so I would definitely argue non-`const`.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect to call the function using a const pointer or reference, you must mark the function `const` to be able to do so. Otherwise it's completely up to you.

Edit: Giving this some more thought. Your object probably contains a handle to an OS window, and this handle can be passed to OS functions. The handle doesn't really have a concept of constness so it's an impedance mismatch with C++, but the function you pass it to will either be querying a window property (const) or modifying the window in some way (non-const). It would be useful for your object to enforce the constness concept even though the OS does not.

Comment: I understand the c++ language issues, it's more a question about what is a good design. Perhaps the only answer is "it depends..."

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have this situation:

- For each API window, there is at most one C++ window object.
- A C++ window object is not copyable (including that it is not cloneable).

For this case it is possible to use `const` in the C++ object interface, so as to let client code offer no-state-change guarantees by e.g. declaring some parameter as `const`.

However, as soon as one or both constraint are removed, it becomes a futile and meaningless exercise. Consider, for example, removing the second constraint, making the C++ objects copyable. That might seem to make sense, treating the C++ objects almost like `shared_ptr` instances (except for destruction).

But any `const shared_ptr` can be copied to a non-`const` one, so any non-`const` methods can easily be called. For example, `shared_ptr::get` is a `const` method so that it can be called on a `const shared_ptr` object. But its result is `T*`, i.e. no `const` propagation to the result, because even if it was `T const*` it would not really restrict the client code: the client code could just copy that `const shared_ptr` to a non-`const` one, and then call `get` on the non-`const` instance.

Still, with both gurantees above in place the fact that `const` (or in your case the absence of `const`) *can* be used in a  possibly useful way to restrict operations on the referred API window, does not mean that it is necessarily a good idea to do it.

In particular, objects that represent windows are usually event receivers, and in my experience, events do not mix very well with `const`.

However, most programmers are used to pure *inspectors* being `const`. And for that usage, just improving the readability of the code, I would recommend `const` methods. For example, an inspector that returns the window size, would in my view better be `const` than non-`const`.

Comment: I agree with not copying, but you could pass a const reference to a function that needs to for example obtain the width and height of a window maybe?